# Send signals over USB using cocoa?

Tags: xcode, macos, usb, iokit

Just wondering, is there any "API" for sending signals through a USB cable to a device using Apple's cocoa programming language, so I could incorporate it with an app?

is it much more complicated than a couple of commands, or do i need a library?

I have no experience with external device communication so any help is welcomed!

Comment: Cocoa is not a programming language, it's a set of APIs. Objective-C is the programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to read up on [`IOKit`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do USB on OS X.  There are some cross-platform libraries like [`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/) that can come in handy, too.  What kind of device do you want to use?

Comment: great, thanks (I have a lot of reading up to do),
and I don't have a single device in mind yet, just transferring data.